# play the defined part of an audio

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a text and want to play only sentences by clicking on it.

```
<p class="sent hover 00 06">text 01</p>
<p class="sent hover 06 11">text 02</p>
<p class="sent hover 11 18">text 03</p>
<audio controls id="audioB"><source src="lev01/english.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

js

```
$(document).on("click", ".sent", function() {
    var a=$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[2];
    var b=$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[3];
    //$("#audioB")[0].pause();
    $("#audioB")[0].currentTime = a;
    $("#audioB")[0].play();
    $("#audioB")[0].addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if ($("#audioB")[0].currentTime >= b) {
    $("#audioB")[0].pause();
    }
}, false);
});
```

It works if I click any sentence and after that click on sentence before it.

But it doesn't work in vice versa case, i.e. if I click on a sentence which is placed after the previously clicked one.

Any help ?

Comment: I'm not certain if the order of classes is guaranteed. In any case, it would be better to put data in _data-* attributes_, e.g. `data-audio-start="00" data-audio-end="06"`

Comment: @PaulS., `alert (a)` and `alert (b)` works well by clicking on each sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your *HTML* move *data* into attributes meant for holding *data*

```html
<p class="sent hover" data-audiostart="00" data-audioend="06">text 01</p>
<p class="sent hover" data-audiostart="06" data-audioend="11">text 02</p>
<p class="sent hover" data-audiostart="11" data-audioend="18">text 03</p>
<audio controls id="audioB"><source src="lev01/english.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Then you need to create a closure over a variable (e.g. `end`) which holds the time to stop playback which is...

- Accessed by an event handler on *timeupdate* events to see if playback should be paused
- Modified by a function which also sets the *currentTime* and plays the audio file (this function is what we return out of the closure and used to play our audio segments of interest)

For example, after the `<audio>` exists, run the following code

```js
// init
var playSegment = (function (audio) { // closure by IIFE
    var end; // our variable

    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (e) { // handler to pause playback
        if (this.currentTime >= end) {
            this.pause();
        }
    });

    return function (start_time, end_time) { // function to start playback
        audio.currentTime = start_time;
        end = end_time;
        audio.play();
    };
}(document.getElementById('audioB'))); // invoking IIFE with the <audio>

// usage
$(document).on('click', '.sent', function () {
    playSegment(
        parseFloat(this.dataset['audiostart']), // time lookups
        parseFloat(this.dataset['audioend'])
    );
});
```

Comment: Paul, with your code I have this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite.`

Comment: @bonaca oh silly me, I forgot what hyphens did D: ~~~ **edited**

Comment: Excellent, it works. Thanks a lot. But, I still don't know where is the problem with my code.

Comment: @bonaca yours was adding a new listener for every click with a static end time, but not removing old ones when new sections were chosen, meaning the old end times were still being applied, e.g. if you had an end time at 6 seconds previously then tried to start from 12 seconds, immediately it'd be like "woah hold up there, this is more than 6 seconds in". You can't simply clear the listeners either because what would happen if there was a new click before the previous one stopped playing? it starts to get messy, so the solution is to use a single listener which has it's end point moved instead